# cakephp rollback transactions

Tags: cakephp

I've checked out transactions in Cakephp, unfortunately it looks as if it only works with in a single model.  I have a complicated set of updates and inserts spanning across 11 models.  I gather all the information together create the associative arrays representing the data that needs to be updated or inserted, and do all the necessary Model->save() calls.

If any of these fail for any reason, I'd like to roll back everything.  Short of just keeping a list of all the calls made and the old data that the calls are replacing and "rolling back" manually, is there any support for this in CakePHP?  or what is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: i added edit 0 for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stephen,

using transactions in CakePHP requires that your database engine supports transactions.
Maybe [this](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1633/Transactions) comes in handy.
If saving multiple associated models in one run is the task, going for [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) with atomic option set to true is the way.

**Edit0:** I wonder it [this](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/guille1983/2011/01/10/database_transactions) does any good?

Comment: that's the documentation I was looking at earlier, the begin() function requires that I pass a Model, when using multiple models, which one would I pass?  and will that transaction all of the mnodels, or do I need to do a $datasource->begin() with all the models I'm using, and then at the end use the commit() and rollback() on each one?

Comment: if all of your models are properly associated, the saveAll should work. if not, the nature of transactions says there is one begin at the start of whatever you are doing and one commit or rollback at the end. in case of cakephp you cannot nest the transactions. all of your models should be reachable via your datasource (e.g. model data stored in the same database).

Comment: gah, my daily vote limit has been reached, it's been a busy day. I'll have to up vote you in a few hours.  I used the base model that everything is built off of, Rental, all other models are associated, and the rollbacks and commits worked great, thanks.